# aws cloudformation package command not found on aws-cli/1.10.56

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I am a AWS noob and have been task to investigate serverless deployment.

I am following the examples in:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/serverless-deploy-wt.html
as well as
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/package.html
and am experiencing the above. It seems that "**aws cloudformation**" simply do not have the "**package**" command.

Here's the output of my "aws cloudformation package" command:

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...]
[parameters] To see help text, you can run:

aws help   aws <command> help   aws <command> <subcommand> help aws:
error: argument operation: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

cancel-update-stack |
continue-update-rollback |
create-change-set | 
create-stack |
delete-change-set | 
delete-stack |
describe-account-limits | 
describe-change-set |
describe-stack-events | 
describe-stack-resource |
describe-stack-resources | 
describe-stacks |
estimate-template-cost | 
execute-change-set |
get-stack-policy | 
get-template |
get-template-summary | 
list-change-sets |
list-stack-resources | 
list-stacks |
set-stack-policy | 
signal-resource |
update-stack | 
validate-template |
wait | 
help
```

Any advice greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: it seems to me that my aws-cli is a 1.10.[*] version. I have used the "curl approach" to update the aws-cli and "aws cloudformation package" has appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`aws cloudformation package` was added in AWS CLI 1.11.19.  See the [1.11.19 changelog](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.rst#11119) for more details.

Simply update away from 1.10.56 and try again, since this old version that you are currently using won't have the new command.

An aside: This [AWS CLI Changelog](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.rst) seems more up-to-date than the official [release notes](https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/CLI) pages; I'm not sure if that's an inconsistency or if they've just stopped supporting them.

Comment: Thanks for that, @Anthony Neace. Just a note here: in the SAM Template ecosystem, `aws cloudformation package` is typically followed by `aws cloudformation deploy`. This will not work if your packaged template is > 50KB (?). One has to do this instead: `package` -> `upload template to S3` -> `create change set from s3` -> `execute change set`.